# Proper Powershell formatting SSL Cert Where | FriendlyName like $variable

Tags: powershell, ssl-certificate, veeam

Thanks for reading, I'm working on something a bit outside my element and trying to write a powershell script that can install some SSL Certificates into some Veeam Products.

This works.

```
Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
Connect-VBRServer
$certificate = Get-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -FromStore | Where FriendlyName -like "*12/10/2019*"
Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -Certificate $certificate
Disconnect-VBRServer
```

What I need though is a way for the `-like "*12/10/2019*"` to be a variable that inserts today's date.

I've tried using a variable like this:

```
 $date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Then using

```
-like "*$date*"
```

I've tried something like this

```
-like "*(Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy")*"
```

Here's an output from a failed attempt with formatting recommended below and what Power Shell Returns

```
Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
Connect-VBRServer
$certificate = Get-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -FromStore | Where FriendlyName -like "*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*"
Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -Certificate $certificate
Disconnect-VBRServer
```

Powershell return

> Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Certificate'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the 
>   argument, and then try running the command again.
>   At line:5 char:45
>   + Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -Certificate $certificate
>   +                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate], ParameterBindingValidationException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Veeam.Backup.PowerShell.Cmdlets.AddVBRCloudGatewayCertificate

Go easy on me I'm sure I'm missing something dumb and obvious but I'm not a programmer and my scripting skills are pretty minimal.

Thanks for taking a look and helping out.

Comment: Using a variable should work. If you want to use a nested expression you need `"*$(...)*"`, not `"*(...)*"`. Note that you may need to escape the forward slashes in the format string (`MM\/dd\/yyyy`), b/c IIRC the underlying .net routines replace unescaped forward slashes with the date separator defined in the system's regional settings, which may or may not be a forward slash.

Comment: Still not able to get this to work.   I tried. ` Where FriendlyName -like "*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*" `

Comment: Also tried without the escaping backslashes. Also tried populating the $date variable separately and using `-like "*$(date)*"`

Comment: "Not able to get this to work" is not a valid problem description. Please show an example of a friendly name and the output of `"*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*"`.

Comment: Here's an example of Friendly Name.  `*.xxxx.xxx [Certify] - 10/12/2019 12:37:39 AM to 1/9/2020 11:37:39 PM`

Comment: Here's the last full command I ran.   ` Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapin
Connect-VBRServer
$date = Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
$certificate = Get-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -FromStore | Where FriendlyName -like "*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*"
Add-VBRCloudGatewayCertificate -Certificate $certificate
Disconnect-VBRServer 
`

Comment: Well, today is neither 10/12/2019 nor 1/9/2020, so of course `FriendlyName -like "*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*"` won't match.

Comment: Good point, I would only be running the script on the date the Cert was generated so the Friendly Name and Date should match.    I added some additional information to the original post.   I'll need to go back and regenerate the Cert to today's date and retest this.

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot.   Looks like `FriendlyName -like "*$(Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy")*"` does work, assuming there is an existing Cert with that date in the store.    Sorry that should have been obvious forgot I've been working on this multiple days.